# USB speed bottlenecks (specifically while running virtual machine)

Tags: usb, virtualbox, performance, usb-drive

This question is mostly about USB performance on Linux, but more specifically performance issues when running virtualbox images off of my USB. I posted this on the virtualbox forum, but so far no one has helped me.

**Details**

I bought a new Kingston HyperX Savage 512 GB 3.1 USB stick. 
I copied a 150 GB file on it, verified the hash and it passed. 
I also verified the speed using:

```
time $(sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/host/mnt/testfile2 bs=1M count=1000 & sync)         
1000+0 records in            
1000+0 records out           
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB, 1000 MiB) copied, 3.69425 s, 284 MB/s                                                             
real    0m3.883s             
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Other time it would be around 110 MB/s, but still I think performance is good enough for VirtualBox to run Ubuntu instance on it.

Another benchmark shows the following:

```
sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sdd1        
/dev/sdd1:                    
Timing cached reads:   21882 MB in  1.99 seconds = 10973.39 MB/sec                                                     
Timing buffered disk reads: 1204 MB in  3.00 seconds = 400.74 MB/sec
```

What happens is that when I start the VirtualBox, there are pauses or lags happening. 
A virtual box log of a fresh start and shutdown is located at: https://pastebin.com/iC7kQ54J (cut beginning part out because it was too long).

Based on my research, whenever there is lagging there are a lot of the following messages in VBox.log:

```
00:07:10.988753 AsyncCompletion: Task 0x007f65495ff9c0 completed after 16 seconds
00:07:17.981513 AsyncCompletion: Task 0x007f65495ffe80 completed after 23 seconds
00:07:17.989714 AsyncCompletion: Task 0x007f65495ff7c0 completed after 23 seconds
00:07:18.004043 AsyncCompletion: Task 0x007f65495ffec0 completed after 23 seconds
00:07:18.009427 AsyncCompletion: Task 0x007f65495fffc0 completed after 23 seconds
00:07:18.065390 AsyncCompletion: Task 0x007f65495ffd80 completed after 23 seconds
00:07:18.065474 AsyncCompletion: Task 0x007f65495ff840 completed after 23 seconds
```

After googling around, it seems people are saying this has to do with I/O on the drive, but how can that be the case if I get a good
performance on the drive during benchmarks?

Am I bench marking wrong?

Can you suggest a better method?

Are there any other parameters which might be disabled which are causing virtual-box to have performance issues with my USB?

There are no errors in dmesg on the host during a run of this virtual machine.

Here is sudo lshw | grep -A26 -B10 Kingston for my USB:

```
          *-usb:1
               description: Mass storage device
               product: HyperX Savage
               vendor: Kingston
               physical id: 6
               bus info: usb@4:6
               logical name: scsi8
               version: 1.00
               capabilities: usb-3.10 scsi emulated scsi-host
               configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=896mA speed=5000Mbit/s
             *-disk
                  description: SCSI Disk
                  product: HyperX Savage
                  vendor: Kingston
                  physical id: 0.0.0
                  bus info: scsi@8:0.0.0
                  logical name: /dev/sdd
                  version: PMAP
                  size: 468GiB (503GB)
                  capabilities: removable
                  configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                *-medium
                     physical id: 0
                     logical name: /dev/sdd
                     size: 468GiB (503GB)
                     capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                     configuration: signature=6e13cd5d
                   *-volume
                        description: EXT4 volume
                        vendor: Linux
                        physical id: 1
                        logical name: /dev/sdd1
                        logical name: /home/host/mnt
                        version: 1.0
                        serial: e953210a-43c2-4ba9-87ec-55ed8ab3c6ff
                        size: 468GiB
                        capacity: 468GiB
                        capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                        configuration: created=2018-09-01 00:55:53 filesystem=ext4 label=datapartition lastmountpoint=/home/host/mnt modified=2018-09-01 12:50:22 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,data=ordered mounted=2018-09-01 12:50:22 state=mounted
```

Can anyone tell what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you really say `&` in that first command?  It looks like there should be a `&&` there.  (Also, the ``$`` seems odd.)

Comment: Agreed, it should be `&&` and I would start the command with `sudo` instead of inside the Bash command substitution (`$()`).

Comment: PS: really well described issue. It's rare to see such a clear question.

Comment: @WillianPaixao so so clear. If you are describing a problem like this, the host system, model processor and USB tech has to be described.

Answer (score 0):

> https://pastebin.com/iC7kQ54J

According to your log, it seems you have KVM installed. (at least the driver seems loaded)
If so, there you have the reason for your lag. Both drivers compete for the same resources. I have done the same years ago and the system responds horribly.

A short-term solution is to unload KVM module before starting Virtualbox.
A long-time solution would uninstall one virtualization application or automate its checks before initialization.

Comment: This did not help. I am assuming the USB is bad in one way or another. I ended using a SSD drive and everything works beautifully :)

Answer (score 0):

From your own question, the USB write times are half the read time under optimum conditions. It seem you are not taking it account buffers, and those speeds are extremely favourable compared to the actual performance of the device.

So try:

time $(sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/home/host/mnt/testfile2 bs=1M count=1000 )
time $(sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/home/host/mnt/testfile2 bs=1M count=1000 & sync)

And look at the timing of the second operation.

Doing concurrent operations also does not lend itself well over this medium, and it will bring it to an halt.  The life of such device under such use will be short, those kind of medium was not designed for such use.

Usually also hypervisors need lots of I/O, they might be constantly saving the VM image in addition to the I/O operations of the VMs, and some technologies also do regular snapshots.

In short, you are trying to give it an use which it was not designed for, it won´t work no matter how you try to optimize it.

PS. I also have an USB pen of the "same" model, except smaller capacity, and that model is a very poor choice, they are *slow* under normal usage. The specs of the manufacturer look good on paper, however they often are timing operations with amounts of data that fit on their RAM buffer.

PS2. You are saying the device is USB 3.1 but not telling us the technology of your device.